# Caption/Space problem in tikz/pgf/subcaptionbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, pgfplots, subcaption

I plot 4 Graphs with Tikz and use subcaptionbox. Following badnesses occur:
(1) There is no space between the caption of the upper figure to the figure below. 
(2) The second figures (b) caption starts nearly in the caption of the left (a).

See the attached figure for clarity.

Thanks in advance
Problems: [image]
MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=12pt, open=any, numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3.5cm, right=2.0cm, top=2.0cm, bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\subcaptionbox{Dies ist ein Satz, der sehr schlecht umgebrochen wird}{%
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$t$},ylabel={$y$ [\%]}, xmin=0, xmax=12.8, ymin=-3.0, ymax=5.0, grid, width=7.5cm]
\addplot plot [color=black, mark=no] table{xxx.txt};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\subcaptionbox{Dies ist ein Satz, der sehr schlecht umgebrochen wird}
{
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$t$},ylabel={$y$[\%]}, xmin=0, xmax=12.8, ymin=-3.0, ymax=5.0, grid, width=7.5cm]
\addplot plot [color=black, mark=no] table{xxx.txt};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subcaptionbox{Dies ist ein Satz, der sehr schlecht umgebrochen wird}{%
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$t$},ylabel={$y$ [\%]}, xmin=0, xmax=12.8, ymin=-3.0, ymax=5.0, grid, width=7.5cm]
\addplot plot [color=black, mark=no] table{xxx.txt};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\subcaptionbox{Dies ist ein Satz, der sehr schlecht umgebrochen wird}
{
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$t$},ylabel={$y$ [\%]}, xmin=0, xmax=12.8, ymin=-3.0, ymax=5.0, grid, width=7.5cm]
\addplot plot [color=black, mark=no] table{xxx.txt};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{Hier ist alles OK Hier ist alles OK Hier ist alles OK Hier ist alles OK Hier ist alles OK }
\label{fig:aaaaa}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the spacing commands `\hspace` and `\vspace` to get your desired spacing. You can see where I've added them in the code below. Note that I minimized your preamble for this example slightly, and in particular, [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) already loads [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf), so loading `tikz` separately is not necessary.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=12pt, open=any, numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3.5cm, right=2.0cm, top=2.0cm, bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\subcaptionbox{Dies ist ein Satz, der sehr schlecht umgebrochen wird}{%
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$t$},ylabel={$y$ [\%]}, xmin=0, xmax=12.8, ymin=-3.0, ymax=5.0, grid, width=7.5cm]
\addplot plot [color=black, mark=no] {x};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}}
%
\hspace{1cm}
%
\subcaptionbox{Dies ist ein Satz, der sehr schlecht umgebrochen wird}{%
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$t$},ylabel={$y$[\%]}, xmin=0, xmax=12.8, ymin=-3.0, ymax=5.0, grid, width=7.5cm]
\addplot plot [color=black, mark=no] {x};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}}%
%
\vspace{1cm}
%
\subcaptionbox{Dies ist ein Satz, der sehr schlecht umgebrochen wird}{%
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$t$},ylabel={$y$ [\%]}, xmin=0, xmax=12.8, ymin=-3.0, ymax=5.0, grid, width=7.5cm]
\addplot plot [color=black, mark=no] {x};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}}%
%
\hspace{1cm}
%
\subcaptionbox{Dies ist ein Satz, der sehr schlecht umgebrochen wird}{%
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$t$},ylabel={$y$ [\%]}, xmin=0, xmax=12.8, ymin=-3.0, ymax=5.0, grid, width=7.5cm]
\addplot plot [color=black, mark=no] {x};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\caption{Hier ist alles OK Hier ist alles OK Hier ist alles OK Hier ist alles OK Hier ist alles OK }
\label{fig:aaaaa}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I searched appr. for two days for a solution, and after all, the secrets which solved my problems with alignment, formatting etc. where `}%` `\hspace` and `subcaptionbox`. Here is my version, I hope it helps other user who want to add plots directly into the LaTex code side-by-side + subcaptionbox and correct alignment.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Influence of PZT content on (a) the piezoelectric $d_{33}$ of (b) the dielectric $\epsilon$ of the PZT/PVDF composite\cite{zhang2008structural}}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, trim axis left]
\begin{axis}[legend pos=north west, xlabel=PZT contents $Vol\%$, ylabel=$d_{33}$ (pC/N)]
\addplot coordinates {
(3.992E+001,    6.879E+000)
(5.004E+001,    1.287E+001)
(5.992E+001,    1.995E+001)
(7.004E+001,    2.400E+001)
(8.008E+001,    3.093E+001)
};
\addplot coordinates {
(3.992E+001,    1.505E+001)
(5.004E+001,    2.307E+001)
(6.000E+001,    3.396E+001)
(7.004E+001,    4.096E+001)
(8.000E+001,    3.497E+001)
};
\legend{Cold press,Hot press}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\hspace{1cm}
\subcaptionbox{Influence of PZT content on (a) the piezoelectric $d_{33}$ of (b) the dielectric $\epsilon$ of the PZT/PVDF composite\cite{zhang2008structural}}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[legend pos=north west, xlabel=PZT contents $Vol\%$, ylabel=$d_{33}$ (pC/N)]
\addplot coordinates {
(3.992E+001,    6.879E+000)
(5.004E+001,    1.287E+001)
(5.992E+001,    1.995E+001)
(7.004E+001,    2.400E+001)
(8.008E+001,    3.093E+001)
};
\addplot coordinates {
(3.992E+001,    1.505E+001)
(5.004E+001,    2.307E+001)
(6.000E+001,    3.396E+001)
(7.004E+001,    4.096E+001)
(8.000E+001,    3.497E+001)
};
\legend{Cold press,Hot press}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\caption{Potentail diagram of the extraction.}
\label{fig:potential}
\end{figure}
```

[image]